# Adding Multiple Empty Columns in PySpark DataFrame

Tags: python, pyspark

Can anyone suggest how can I add multiple empty columns in a pyspark dataframe. Currently I am doing something like this but its not working :

```
def add_columns(dataframe, column_list):
    for col in column_list:
        self = dataframe.withColumn(str(col), lit(None).cast(StringType())))
    return dataframe
```

In the output schema after the add_columns function is applied , I get new column as generator object genexpr at 0x7f41189d7e10: string (nullable = true)

Comment: Try replacing `lit(None)` with `lit('')`?

Comment: what is column_list? what values are there? `str(col)`  what do you expect here? maybe it should be col.name instead.

Answer (score 0):

Your code snippet is working for me, just make this small change inside:

```
def add_columns(dataframe, column_list):
    self = dataframe.withColumn(str(column_list[0]), f.lit(None).cast(StringType()))
    for col in column_list[1:]:
        self = self.withColumn(str(col), f.lit(None).cast(StringType()))
    return self
```

I returned "self" instead of "dataframe" to not adding multiple columns to dataframe every time the function is run.